# animation javascript on words

Tags: javascript, animation, text

I'm new coding in Javascript and I'm wondering how can I do this example using js; with an array of words and selecting the speed of highlighted between each word

example: [animation words javascript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8j6j.gif)

Comment: Can you share some code you have written so far?

Comment: hi, as I said, I'm just learning js, I just know the basics, that's why I was wondering if anyone can help me guiding me thru this

Comment: using canvas? there a lot animation library for achieve that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is so many ways you can achieve this.
i will just show you the ugliest way
this is using pure javascript with setInterval method.

```js
var arrOfWord=["cat","dog","fun","sat","wen","ten","sun","net","hat"];
var arrOfDiv=[];
var con=document.getElementById("container");
for(var i in arrOfWord){
  con.innerHTML+="<div id='word-box'>"+arrOfWord[i]+"</str>";
}
arrOfDiv=con.children;
window.setInterval(
(function(){
  var next=0;
function highlightWord(){
 
  if (next>arrOfDiv.length-1){
    next=0;
    }
  if (next==0){
    arrOfDiv[arrOfDiv.length-1].style="border: 2px solid #00000000";
  }
  else arrOfDiv[next-1].style="border: 2px solid #00000000";
  arrOfDiv[next].style="border: 2px solid #ffff00";
  next+=1;
}
  return highlightWord;
})(),500
);
```

```css
#word-box{
  display: inline-block;
  padding:5px;
  margin:2px;
  border-radius:5px;
  border: 2px solid #00000000;
}

#container{
  width:140px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
 
</div>
```

Comment: thank you, that helps a lot to make it, now I can understand how to do that because I was thinking making that on canvas but that would be and image right?

Answer (score -1):

Welcome to starting Javascript.

I would start with a tutorial like this:
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/

It will walk you through how to change HTML elements with code.

After your feeling comfortable setting CSS properties with javascript you could look into `setTimout()` or `setInterval` to animate and cycle through the visual changes on a set time schedule.